# how to filter words containing numbers when doing wordcount in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cpu-word

how can I except words containing numbers when do wordcount in Scala

newest version Scala

`val reduceOut=sc.textFile("...").flatMap(x=>x.split("\\W+")).map(x=>(x,1)).reduceByKey(_+_)`

my wordcount result contains many non-words such as as follows

...
(tgpa5nwsjf,1198974)
(crwxd7gute,1198974)
(d64eg5gtow,1198974)
...

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude words containing digits by using regex. You need to filter out unnecessary words before mapping their count to 1.Use `filterNot` as shown in below code:

```
sc.textFile("...")
  .flatMap(x=>x.split("\W+"))
  .filterNot(_.matches(".*\\d.*"))  //filter out words containing digits
  .map(x=>(x,1)).reduceByKey(_+_)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes, it helps! But didn't work if use this code directly. So I am still trying and plan to tell you after I succeed. Thank you!